# Serializing pcap file into 4B chunks

Tags: 10gbethernet, pcap

Given a previously generated pcap file, how do I serialize the data into 4B (or N byte) chunks. The format/protocol of the pcap data is not relevant here.

Comment: Built in to what? And 4 octets isn't even enough to store a single packet. You should be looking at larger sizes.

Comment: The application is not relevant. I want to slice raw pcap data into 4B chunks. Is there a simple way to do that through the pcap/libpcap/similar libraries?

Comment: The application is relevant, because that's the most obvious place to actually slice the pcap data, while it's being generated. And you really do not want to slice the data into four byte chunks.

Comment: Other people would say you don't want to capture the data into four byte chunks. Please update your question with a more realistic value like 4KB chunks, you will be more likely to get an answer :).

Comment: I didn't say "capture" in 4B. I said, given a pcap file, I want to serialize the data into 4B chunks.

Comment: What do you mean with “serialize” then?

Comment: Can you improve your question or can't you? That's the only thing that matters ...

Comment: Closing this as you are unwilling or unable to clearly explain what your problem is, although multiple persons have made you aware that this isn't as obvious as you believe it to be.

Comment: Look at the latest comment. Do your research.

Comment: The problem is that you have not clearly explained what you want, despite multiple people asking you to clarify it. Instead you have been exceptionally hostile to everyone who has attempted to understand your problem and help you solve it, and you have absolutely refused to explain what you are trying to do. There's nothing else we can do unless and until you decide to actually allow us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can split a file into multiple files of whatever size you like using the `split` command. Here is an example where I split a previously created `pcap` file into 4 byte chunks:

```
/tmp/wat$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 kasperd kasperd 116 Oct 18 18:19 wat.pcap
/tmp/wat$ split -b4 wat.pcap
/tmp/wat$ ls -l
total 120
-rw-r--r-- 1 kasperd kasperd 116 Oct 18 18:19 wat.pcap
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xab
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xac
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xad
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xae
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xaf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xag
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xah
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xai
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xaj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xak
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xal
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xam
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xan
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xao
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xap
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xaq
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xas
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xau
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xav
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xaw
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xax
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xay
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xaz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xba
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xbb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kasperd kasperd   4 Oct 18 18:20 xbc
/tmp/wat$ cat x* | sha224sum - wat.pcap
14c450277299f320535d369fc5f1044f96725b0afcfec0b9840bb717  -
14c450277299f320535d369fc5f1044f96725b0afcfec0b9840bb717  wat.pcap
/tmp/wat$
```

As you can see even a tiny `pcap` file will produce a lot of files when split into such small chunks. So be careful when using this on a file system which isn't optimized for many small files.

Comment: -1. I'm not looking to  generate more pcap files, rather I want to parse the pcap file in place